# If geokit-rails no longer has geo_scope method, what I am supposed to use to get lat/long of an address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, geokit

Looking at the latest release of geokit-rails (2.1.0), it looks like they have removed the method geo_scope (https://github.com/geokit/geokit-rails/commit/781c4dc62d3b044196efbfad269d4780e6afbe6b).

However, the README on the github account still says to use it.

If the example they provide in the README -- "Location.geo_scope(:origin => '100 Spear st, San Francisco, CA')" -- no longer works whats the new method?

Problem I am trying to solve:

When users register for my site, I collect their mailing address, I need to convert that to lat/long and store it in my database.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you could use an address verification service. Some of these include, SmartyStreets (where I work), Melissa Data, and Lob. I'm not a huge expert with the other providers, but I know with SmartyStreets you can use the street API to get latitude and longitude from an address and have the comfort of knowing that the address exists. SmartyStreets has both a [US Street API](https://smartystreets.com/docs/address) and an [International Street API](https://smartystreets.com/docs/international)

If you use a non address verification service like Google Maps, you run the risk of approximate latitude and longitude coordinates being returned to you.